# Evaluation of IF statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me try to understand the evaluation of this script. It must be something simple I'm not understanding. I want to scan a text file and output lines with specific string value.

So for example my txt file will contain simple stuff:

```
beep
boop 
bop 
Hey 
beep
boop
bop
```

and the script is looking for the line with "Hey" and trying to output that line

```
file_path = "C:\\downloads\\test.txt"
i = 0
file_in = open(file_path,"r+") # read & write
for lines in file_in.readlines():
    i+=1
    #if lines.rfind("this entity will be skipped..."):
    if lines.find("Hey"):
        print(i, lines)
file_in.close()
```

For some reason it outputs every line except the one it found a match on. How is this possible?

Comment: Try this `if  ! lines.find("Hey"):`

Comment: Don't try that. Try reading the docs for the `find` method: "Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found...Return -1 on failure." That means if it's at the beginning of the string, `find` returns `0`.  So you want `if lines.find(...) >= 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably more straightforward to do `if "Hey" in lines:` instead of `if lines.find("Hey"):`.  If you really want to use `find()`, you could do this: `if lines.find("Hey") != -1:`

Answer (score 4):

While Daniel's answer is, of course, correct and should be accepted, I want to fuel my OCD and offer some improvements:

```
# use context managers to automatically release file handler
with open(file_path) as file_in:
    # file objects are iterable, will return lines 
    # reading entire file in memory can crash if file is too big
    # enumerate() is a more readable alternative to manual counters
    for i, line in enumerate(file_in):  # 'line' should be singular 
        if "Hey" in line:  # same as Daniel
             print(i, line)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.find(sub)` returns an **integer** - the first index of `sub` if `sub` is found, and -1 if it is not.

When "Hey" is present, it is at the first index (0), so that is what `.find()` returns. Otherwise, "Hey" is not found, so `.find()` returns -1.

Since python treats all integers as True except 0, then the conditional evaluates to True when 0 is returned, i.e. when "Hey" is found.

Change your use of .find() to something which fulfills your if statement the way you want.